# Error on downloading file with node-webkit ( "chrome-extension" in the URL)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, google-chrome, node-webkit

I'm trying to make something like pdf downloader with node-webkit. 
I have an input tag for the URL with some validation code. 
it works just fine so far .. but when i try to put URL like this one
(chrome extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www.semantikon.com/StealThisBookbyAbbieHoffman.pdf)
node web-kit gives me this error :

```
message: "Protocol "chrome-extension:" not supported. Expected "http:"."
```

I'm using this regexp

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?\.pdf$/gi;
```

Thanks

Comment: I know it's because the "chrome extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/" but maybe the users of this app wont know ..so how do i solve it ..or remove it without affecting the pdf file to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since now one answered i'll do this myself, i did something not very nice but it works for now .. i put some function to make sure the the url starts with http or https , but in this case the use have to remove the unnecessary parts of the url like the example above

```
chrome extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www.semantikon.com/StealThisBookbyAbbieHoffman.pdf
```